# Vue.js drag-select for selecting multiple divs?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I'm working on an app that handles some kind of reservations by time and by court (Tennis court). I don't use tables, instead I use divs to draw a table. Horizontally I have 'courts' while vertically I have 'hours'. If user clicks on one div, let's say 'court 1, 10:00h' I store that as one event. The point is, some of reservations should be for 2h and more. So I would love to create some kind of 'drag-select' which will highlight few divs, i.e. 'court 1, from 10:00 - 12:00'. After that I would store start and end to the db.

How would you approach this problem? I didn't find any similar package that I can use.

Comment: could show the relevant parts of your code ?

Comment: It's an idea for now.

Comment: Good it's interesting, so could you share some code in https://codesandbox.io in order to work on

Comment: https://github.com/stephan281094/vue-drag-select